# Uploading to Someone Else's Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have a huge chunk of data on my hard disk which I'd like to give away to someone else. Unlike me, this other guy has a lot of available storage space on his Google Drive. Thus, uploading the data to my Google Drive and then sharing it with him is impossible (and isn't either really my objective: I want to give it to him not share with him). Is there a way for me to upload the data directly to his Google Drive other than by signing in to his account?

Comment: I know of no way to upload data to a Google Drive unless you actually signed into the Google account in question.  You should just purchase additional space and/or open an additional Google account.

Comment: @Isaac: How much data are we talking about (ballpark)?

Comment: @AlEverett: about 25 GB

Comment: @Isaac - 25 GB?!? How long are you willing to wait to upload this? How long is he willing to wait to download it?  It would probably be faster to just mail the guy a 32 GB microSD card, or, even better, walk it over to him...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is very possible. Here is how:

1. Have the person create a collection **just** for the data you want to give him.
   Have him share that collection with you (make sure he gives you edit permissions).
2. Open the Google Drive web interface and drag the collection from "Shared with me" to "My Drive"
3. Get the Google Drive desktop app (if you don't have it already, click on "Download Google Drive" in the web interface)
4. While setting up Google Drive, used the Advanced options to choose which collections to sync.
5. Choose the collection (currently empty) that was created in step 1
6. Copy the files you want to upload into that collection (folder) on your hard drive. It will then sync the files to **their** Google Drive folder.
7. When you are finished, just stop syncing the Collection and/or he can un-share the collection with you.

It may *look* complicated, but it's actually much simpler than you might think. I use this for shipping very large amounts of data around. The fact Google Drive has a maximum file size of 10Gb helps too.

Comment: Did not work. I tried your advice but the message says that I have "insufficient storage." Instead of uploading to his/her drive, I ended up mine instead!\

Comment: This no longer seems to work unfortuntely, I tried this exact method and it used my storage, possibly as well as theirs

Answer (score 5):

There is [EntourageBox](http://www.entouragebox.com), which allows you to upload directly to someone's cloud storage, including Google Drive.

Ask him to visit entouragebox.com and create a share URL for his Google Drive. Then visit the URL and upload your files to his Google Drive.

Comment: EntourageBox seems to have disappeared now.

Answer (score 2):

With that much data to transfer I can see why it will not all fit into a default sized Google Drive. All I can say is you either need to sign into your friends account or consider an alternative.

ADrive offers free 14-day trials for 50GB and up, so you can sign up for one of these and use the free trial instead of your friends Google Drive. I cannot, however, grantee that you are under no obligation from the trials, because I have not tried one. Be sure to read the agreement.

If all else fails you could get a flash drive and send it snail-mail.

Answer (score 2):

We created the https://driveuploader.com/ exactly for this purpose.

The person can create an upload page. Anybody who knows the link to this page can just drag&drop very large files (hundreds of gigabytes) to his Google Drive account (if he has there enough free space).

The people who are uploading don't even need a Google account - just a web browser.

See this video:

[image: Uploading to Someone Else Google Drive]

The service is available completely for free - and it supports the unlimited size of the files. There are advertisements on the uploading page.

You can use the DriveUploader.com for business (with your company branding, embedding in websites to receive data from your customers, or integration with products or workflow with APIs and webhooks) which is then paid.